# Removing novalidate to a particular field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

How can i remove the property of required to the Second Element "Second Name" ?

**Here is my Code :**

```html
<form action="#" novalidate>
  First Name:
       <input type="text" name="first" required>
  Second Name : 
       <input type="text" name="second" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _to the Second one "Class"_

Comment: Updated for your understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `required` property to `false`

```js
$("input[name=class]").prop("required", false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
Name: <input type="text" name="name" required>
Class: <input type="text" name="class" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you can do:

```
$('input[name=second]').prop('required', false);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qfepu49q/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/).

```
$('input[name="class"]').removeAttr('required')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the

removeAttribute command:

First set ID's for the inputs.

I set it to the same value as the name.

Next removeAttribute

```
document.getElementById("class").removeAttribute("required");
```

This should do the trick ;)

Here, have a fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77uqmszf/1/)

Comment: Answer is almost the same as the one by Kartikeya, but in plain Javascript and not JQuery

Comment: and the original html doesn't have an id - so you need to mention adding this for your js to work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="text"][name="second"]').prop('required', false);
```

it just removes the required property on the target element which has the name "second".